# Nusoap accessing $this inside method - using $this when not in object context

Tags: php, codeigniter, nusoap

I have a nusoap class, with some methods defined in the constructor. The problem I'm having however, is calling a method either from a model I loaded or a method defined in the same class out of the constructor. The error I get is "Using $this when not in object context". None of the methods are static, so I'm not sure why it's having trouble accessing this. For reference, here is an example of what I'm trying to do.

edit: This is my first time working with nusoap, and the methods were defined in the constructor in all the examples I saw. If the methods do not need to be defined in the constructor, where do I define them?

```
class MySoapServer extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct() { 
       parent::__construct();
       //where I'm loading all my models and libraries, 
       //creating a new instance of soap server
       //and registering all my methods


       function myFunction() {
            $this->testFunction() //this is where it errors out
       }
    }

    function testFunction() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function is in another function, it should look like:

```
class MySoapServer extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct() { 
       parent::__construct();
       //where I'm loading all my models and libraries, 
       //creating a new instance of soap server
       //and registering all my methods


    }
    function myFunction() {
        $this->testFunction() //this is where it errors out
    }
    function testFunction() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

What you seem to be trying to do is run testFunction() in the constructor? If that's the case then myFunction() isn't needed and you just need to add $this->testFunction() at the end of the constructor.

Like this:

```
class MySoapServer extends CI_Controller {
        function __construct() { 
           parent::__construct();
           //where I'm loading all my models and libraries, 
           //creating a new instance of soap server
           //and registering all my methods
           $this->testFunction();
        }
        function testFunction() {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: That was just an example for simplicity, my functions do a lot more than just return true.

Comment: I would imagine so, but that still doesn't justify functions in the constructor. Can you explain why you feel the need to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm Not an expert on nusoap but PHP does not handle nested function very well. Why would you declare "myFunction" inside of the constructor? Try removing the nested function out of the constructor. Also, you might want to try and set the access modifiers of the function.

Comment: The reason I have it in the constructor is because the sdk I'm using requires a series of functions to be called with its own passed in parameters. If I define them outside the constructor I would need to call the methods myself, not having parameters to supply